# A quantity associated with a Riemannian surface

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Assume that  $E$ is a  Riemannian  vector  bundle, then its structure  group is  reduced to  $O(n)$. Then the  structure  group  of  $E \oplus E$ is  reduced to $D(O(n) \oplus O(n)) \subset Sp(2n)$ where $$D(O(n) \oplus O(n))=\{ A\oplus A\mid A \in O(n)\}$$

So there  is  a  natural  symplectic  structure $\omega $ on each  fiber of $E \oplus E$.(We  use  a   maximal atlas of trivialization charts for  $E \oplus E$    whose  structure  group is  contained in $D(O(n) \oplus O(n))$.

let  $T:E \to E \oplus E$  be  an  arbitrary morphism.  We pull back $\omega $  to $T^*(\omega)$. So  $T^*(\omega)$  is a   $2$-  form on each fiber of $E$.

The  above  construction can be  applied  to  $E=TM$ where  $M$ is a  compact  Riemannian  $2$  dimensional  manifold.

Associated  with  a compact Riemannian  surface $(M,g)$, we  define a a  quantity $q(M,g)$  as follows:  $$q(M,g) =\sup_T |\int_M T^*(\omega)|$$  where $T$ varies  on all isometric  embedding of  $TM$ into $TM \oplus TM$ where the latter is equipped with the product metric.

> Is this  quantity finite? Is it independent  of  choosing a  maximal trivialization  atlas  for  $TM \oplus TM$  whose  transition maps are  contained in $D(O(n) \oplus O(n))$?
>
> If  the  answer of the  above  question  is "yes", what  would  be  an interpretation  of this  quantity $q(M,g)$?

Note that the  same  construction can  be  repeated  for an arbitrary compact  $2k$  dimensional  manifold  by  integration of  ${(T^*(\omega))}^k$ on $M$.

Comment: Reminds me of Courant algebroid constructions. Is that what you're going for?

Comment: @AHusain  thanks for your comment. I am not aware of such construction. Is this construction related to my question? I search in wikipedia for Courant algebroid. Thank you for informing me of that.

Comment: Actually, it is almost the opposite of this question. There you typically want the map $E \to E \bigoplus E$ (turn one into $E^\vee$) to give pullback $0$ rather than as big as possible.

Comment: @AHusain  Are  you  referring to  the  folowing  concept?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courant_algebroid

Comment: @AHusain  I really do  not  understand the relation to  my  question.